# Rails 4 cascade save association with validation on belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I'm having troubles autosaving objects which are created this way. Consider having following models:

```
class SearchTerm < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :search_term_occurrences, dependent: :destroy
end

class SearchTermOccurrence < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :search_term
   validates :search_term, presence: true # Problematic validation
   validates_associated :search_term # See Gotchas in answer
end
```

So when I try to do the following:

```
term = SearchTerm.new term: 'something'
term.search_term_occurrences << [SearchTermOccurrence.new, SearchTermOccurrence.new]
term.save!
```

I get the following:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Search term occurrences is invalid, Search term occurrences is invalid
```

But when I omit the validation on belongs_to search_term. Everything is saved properly.

My question is: How to save parent object and its association (newly created) whilst having validations on child objects without saving associated objects one by one and then saving parent object within transaction? I want Rails to handle the transactional logic.

Comment: `belongs_to` associations come with a presence validation by default - you don't need to add one

Comment: That's not true. I still can save SearchTermOccurrence on its own without having SearchTerm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some playing with Rails console I've found an answer. The problem was the order of saving.

I chose different approach of saving: Instead of going from top to bottom (SearchTerm has_many -> SearchTermOccurrences) I tried to save it from the bottom up (SearchTermOccurrence belongs_to -> SearchTerm). So instead of doing this:

```
term = SearchTerm.new term: 'something'
term.search_term_occurrences << [SearchTermOccurrence.new, SearchTermOccurrence.new]
term.save!
```

I did this:

```
occurrence = SearchTermOccurrence.new
occurence.search_term = SearchTerm.new(term: 'search query')
occurence.save!
```

This suddenly worked. So I'm guessing that Rails can only validate parent records in belongs_to association while newly created but cannot validate has_many child records.

## EDIT 1

Gotchas:

If you are choosing this cascade save approach, make sure you add validates_associated for belongs_to record otherwise you might end up with inconsistent database, since `validates :search_term, presence: true` can pass even though SearchTerm itself is invalid. I've added  `validates_associated` to SearchTermOccurrence.

Answer (score 0):

you should save the `term` instance first before adding `SearchTermOccurrence` objects into it.

`term = SearchTerm.new term: 'something'
term.save!
term.search_term_occurrences << [SearchTermOccurrence.new, SearchTermOccurrence.new]`

because `SearchTermOccurrence` have validation of it's parent `SearchTerm` present true so `SearchTerm.new` will not create any ID of `SearchTerm` into database until it is saved.

try above code

Comment: That's not what I want. I want Rails to handle the DB Transaction and autosaving. I don't want to save all objects explicitly as described above.

Comment: then I believe you should go for autosave association option. see the docs here [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html)

Comment: Could you give me example how to set it up? Because it didn't work for me the last time I tried. If i add autosave: true to my has_many association, it still doesn't work.